# Allow SFTP to a single folder not in home directory

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, sftp

I have a web server that I use to host my websites. I have all the websites in folders in /srv/www. There is a Wordpress site that I want to give SFTP access to another developer, how would I go about doing this so that they only have access to /srv/www/thesite.com and not any other directories?

Running Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure chroot using OpenSSH.  Keep in mind that this is not a [definitive security solution](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot).

Specify the following in sshd_config and restart OpenSSH.

```
Match user youruser
         ChrootDirectory /srv/www/thesite.com
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         ForceCommand internal-sftp
```